# Pop up php table value to normal window combobox not working using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, popup

I'm having problem in getting the value from a pop up window frame to a normal window combobox. In the pop up window i've tried to get the value from a php table using a link. I dont no if its the frame which is causing problem or the code... can u help me plz..

The combobox where the value will be input after onClick 

                            Select

search page

function getScriptPage(div_id,content_id,get_count)
        {
            subject_id = div_id;
            content = document.getElementById(content_id).value;
            http.open("GET", "script_page.php?content=" + escape(content)+"&count="+get_count, true);
            http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse;
            http.send(null);
        }

 $('#select .coursetable a.principal').click(function(e){
        var text = $(this).parent().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().text();
        $('ui-autocomplete-input').val(text);
    });

```
<span class="textb">Enter Search Keyword here :</span>
<input type="text" id="text_content" size="30" onKeyUp="getScriptPage('count_display','text_content','1')">
<input type="button" class="login" value="Search" onMouseUp="getScriptPage('output_div','text_content','0')">
    <div id="count_display">

    </div>


<div id="output_div">

</div>
</form>
```

script page

```
include('config.php');

$strlen = strlen($_GET['content']);
$display_count = $_GET['count'];

$select = "select * from course where course_name like '%".$_GET['content']."%' or  course_type like '%".$_GET['content']."%' or duration like '%".$_GET['content']."%' or step_id like '%".$_GET['content']."%'";
$res = mysql_query($select);
$rec_count = mysql_num_rows($res);
if($display_count)
{
  echo "There are <font color='red' size='3'>".$rec_count."</font> matching records found.Click Search to view result.";
}
else
{
```

?>
    
    
        
    
        Search Result
    
    
    
    
       name
       course type
       description
       duration
       step_id

```
if($rec_count > 0)
{
    while($data=mysql_fetch_array($res))

    {
        echo "<tbody>

        <tr>
              <td class='principal'>".$data['course_name']."</td>
              <td class='principal'>".$data['course_type']."</td>
              <td class='principal'>".$data['description']."</td>
              <td class='principal'>".$data['duration']."</td>
              <td class='principal'>".$data['step_id']."</td>

            <td>" .'<a href="" id="select" class="lien2" name="select" value="'.$data['course_name'].'" >Select</a>' ."
```

```
             </tr>
            </tbody>";
    }
}
else
    echo '<td colspan="5" align="center"><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="red">No matching records found....!</FONT></td>';
```

}
?>

i've tried the following javascript code in the search page, but still not working

$('#output_div .coursetable a.principal').click(function(e){
        var text = $(this).parent().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().text();
        $('ui-autocomplete-input').val(text);
    });

or

$('#select .coursetable a').bind('click', function(event) {
        var text = $(this).parent().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().text();
        $('ui-autocomplete-input').val(text);
 });

can you help me plz...

Thx
regards

Comment: Does it have to be a pop up windows *feels sick*, why not a jQuery lightbox style pop up? That'll make it easier to code and better for the UX

Comment: This kind of JavaScript code "parent().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().text();" makes me sick

Comment: @jakenoble : is it possible to include php files on lightbox or only for images??

Answer (score 0):

My honest opinion is not to use a pop up window, but to use something that is better for the user and easier to maintain, no one likes to see `.prev()` multiple times.

You can use a plug in for jQuery like [Boxy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/) which can load a page via Ajax, or it can simply load a predefined form into the lightbox window. This form can then be sumbitted via convention means, or via Ajax.

Boxy provides functions for various events, e.g. what happens when the window is closed, forcing the window to close etc.

Once the form is submitted via Ajax you can then force the window to close if the Ajax response was successful.

Hope that helps.

Comment: hello was just checking the boxy... thx man... one question, can i implement a search on it and do wat i wanted to do????

Comment: Define search, a form, the results ... ?

Comment: I cannot answer because I do not know what you mean by search. You can use Boxy to load the results or the search form or both.